# Mapped column value to enum first argument

Tags: java, jpa, enums, entity

I have in DB `String` column with values

```
0101
0111 
1110
```

I want create enum in my entity and add value.

```
public enum MyEnum{
  NEW("0101","created new"), 
  SUCCESS("0111", "created success), 
  ERROR("1110", "created with error");
}
```

And I want mapped values from DB by first argument of MyEnum and get second argument in my code. Something like this:

```
hz.getMyEnum().value() // I need return created new or created success
```

Comment: Tried using an `@AttributeConverter`?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately jpa currently (till 2.1) doesn't support mapping to enum scoped variables

You can either :

1- store the values as `NEW,SUCCESS,ERROR` instead of `0101,0111,1110`

2- keep it as is

3- (inspired from Kovacs answer) you can create a `@Converter <Enum,String>` and insert the string variable name corresponding to the enum and vice versa ... the only thing to consider is that this converter will be tightly coupled to your enum

Answer (score 0):

I know that the question was about JPA – and the other answer states correctly, that JPA 2.1 does not support this kind of mapping... but jOOQ supports it through `org.jooq.impl.EnumConverter` without problems, see https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.10/manual/sql-execution/fetching/data-type-conversion/